# How do I resolve “ambiguous use of 'fetch'” error with Swift 3?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift3

It worked with xcode 7

```
do{
        let seccionesEntidad = try self.contexto?.fetch(peticion!)
        for entity in seccionesEntidad! {
            self.contexto!.delete(entity as! NSManagedObject)
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
```

I don't know what to do for solve it

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by

```
    let seccionesEntidad = try self.contexto?.fetch(peticion!)! as! [SeccionesEntidad]
```

Must specify the returned type